# Парсер для вк записывает в файл только часть данных

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте

Данный код должен собирать все поcnы в пределах заданного количества "amount  = 1000" из группы и записывать их в файл в виде: пост, ветки комментариев к этому посту и тд.  При выполнении данного кода из 856 постов в этой группе вк в файл записывается только 311 постов и выдает такую ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\parser_vk_all_comments\dubl.py", line 167, in 
> comment_writer(all_comments, k)
> File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\parser_vk_all_comments\dubl.py", line 33, in comment_writer
> a_pen.writerow([all_comments[i]['id'], all_comments[i]['text'], all_comments[i]['likes']['count'], '-', 'comment',
> KeyError: 'text':

Код:

```
import csv
import requests

token = 'token'
version = 5.131
owner_id = '-174228153'
post_id = 0
comment_id = 0
count = 1000
amount = 1000
i = 0


def file_create():
    with open('parsing.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(['id', 'text', 'likes', 'reposts', 'type', 'parents_stak', 'owner_id'])


# функция записи данных в файл

def post_writer(all_post, i):  # i индекс поста из списка
    with open('parsing.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        i = i
        a_pen.writerow((all_post[i]['id'], all_post[i]['text'], all_post[i]['likes']['count'],
                        all_post[i]['reposts']['count'], 'post', '-', all_post[i]['owner_id']))


def comment_writer(all_comments, i):  # получает на вход спиок коментов и индекс комента в списке
    with open('parsing.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow([all_comments[i]['id'], all_comments[i]['text'], all_comments[i]['likes']['count'], '-', 'comment',
        all_comments[i]['post_id'], all_comments[i]['owner_id']])


def subcomment_writer(all_undercom):  # получает на вход список субкоментов и все их записывает в файл
    with open('parsing.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        t = 0
        for subcom in all_undercom:
            while t < len(all_undercom):
                a_pen.writerow((all_undercom[t]['id'], all_undercom[t]['text'], all_undercom[t]['likes']['count'], '-',
                                'subcomment',
                                all_undercom[t]['id'], all_undercom[t]['owner_id']))
                t += 1
            else:
                pass


# получение всех постов

def get_posts(token, owner_id, amount):
    token = token
    version = 5.131
    owner_id = owner_id
    count = 100
    offset = 0
    all_posts = []

    while offset < amount:
        response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',
                                params={
                                    'access_token': token,
                                    'v': version,
                                    'owner_id': owner_id,
                                    'count': count,
                                    'offset': offset
                                })
        data = response.json()['response']['items']
        offset += 100
        all_posts.extend(data)

    return all_posts


# Получение id текущего поста

def get_post_id(all_post, i):
    for post in all_post:
        post_id = all_post[i]['id']

        return post_id


# получение всех коментариев под постом

def get_comments(token, owner_id, post_id, amount):
    token = token
    version = 5.131
    owner_id = owner_id
    post_id = post_id
    count = 100
    offset = 0
    all_comments = []

    while offset < amount:
        response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments',
                                params={
                                    'access_token': token,
                                    'v': version,
                                    'owner_id': owner_id,
                                    'post_id': post_id,
                                    'need_likes': 1,
                                    'count': count,
                                    'offset': offset
                                })
        data = response.json()['response']['items']
        offset += 100
        all_comments.extend(data)
    return all_comments


# получение id текущего комментария
def get_comment_id(all_comments, i):
    comment_id = None
    for coment in all_comments:
        if i < len(all_comments):
            comment_id = all_comments[i]['id']
        else:
            pass
        return comment_id


# получение ветки подкоментариев
def get_vetcom(token, owner_id, post_id, comment_id, amount):
    token = token
    version = 5.131
    owner_id = owner_id
    post_id = post_id
    comment_id = comment_id
    count = 100
    offset = 0
    all_comments_vet = []

    while offset < amount:
        response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments',
                                params={
                                    'access_token': token,
                                    'v': version,
                                    'owner_id': owner_id,
                                    'post_id': post_id,
                                    'need_likes': 1,
                                    'comment_id': comment_id,
                                    'count': count,
                                    'offset': offset
                                })
        data = response.json()['response']['items']
        offset += 100
        all_comments_vet.extend(data)
    return all_comments_vet


file_create()

all_post = get_posts(token, owner_id, amount)  # получили список постов
print(len(all_post))
all_comments = None
all_undercom = None

while i < len(all_post):
    post_writer(all_post, i)
    post_id = get_post_id(all_post, i)  # получили id текущего поста
    all_comments = get_comments(token, owner_id, post_id, amount)  # получили список коментариев под этим постом
    k = 0
    while k < len(all_comments):
        comment_writer(all_comments, k)
        comment_id = get_comment_id(all_comments, k)  # получили id n-го комментария из списка комментариев
        print(len(all_comments))
        all_undercom = get_vetcom(token, owner_id, post_id, comment_id, amount)  # получили список подкоментариев этого коментария
        print(len(all_undercom))
        subcomment_writer(all_undercom)
        k += 1 
    i += 1

print(len(all_post))
print(1)
```

Если оставить только часть которая записывает только посты без комментариев, то записываются все посты:

```
import csv
import requests

token = 'token'
version = 5.131
owner_id = '-174228153'
post_id = 0
comment_id = 0
count = 1000
amount = 1000
i = 0

def file_create():
    with open('parsing1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(['id', 'text', 'likes', 'reposts', 'type', 'parents_stak', 'owner_id'])


# функция записи данных в файл

def post_writer(all_post, i):  # i индекс поста из списка
    with open('parsing1.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        i = i
        a_pen.writerow((all_post[i]['id'], all_post[i]['text'], all_post[i]['likes']['count'],
                        all_post[i]['reposts']['count'], 'post', '-', all_post[i]['owner_id']))


def get_posts(token, owner_id, amount):
    token = token
    version = 5.131
    owner_id = owner_id
    count = 100
    offset = 0
    all_posts = []

    while offset < amount:
        response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',
                                params={
                                    'access_token': token,
                                    'v': version,
                                    'owner_id': owner_id,
                                    'count': count,
                                    'offset': offset
                                })
        data = response.json()['response']['items']
        offset += 100
        all_posts.extend(data)

    return all_posts


file_create()

all_post = get_posts(token, owner_id, amount)  # получили список постов
print(len(all_post))

while i < len(all_post):
    post_writer(all_post, i)
    i += 1
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре нет ключа `text`, возможно на одной из записей в группе расположена только фотография без описания. Как вариант эту ошибку можно обработать через `try` и `except` и ваш код продолжит дальше выполняться.